MongoDB Index for sorting by Date
I have a simple question - maybe too simple so that I don't find an answer:
My collection has documents containing a field startTimestamp of type date. The UI shows the documents in descending order of startTimestamp, so I just order by date:
db.mycollection.find( {} ).sort( {startTimestamp: -1} );
As the collection starts to grow, the query gets slower and slower.
I can not figure out, if I really need an Index for that field? If so, are there any disadvantages?
I tried to create an index but was not sure if the query time gets faster

It is unclear what you are asking for. Did you actually build an index to support the query? If so, what is your index definition? Also, have you checked explain() to see if the index is correctly supporting your query?

The question is: do I really need (in general) an index (for date) for sorting by date?

@hnwoh's answer should give you some insight. Generally speaking, if your application has high read/write ratio (i.e. reads are more frequent than writes), an index will boost the overall performance. On the contrary, if writes are more often, indices may potentially slow down your application.

Problem solved, the reason was just that the compute instance running mongod had too low memory (~ 1 GB). After increasing memory, everything runs good with no index

As a rule of thumb, if you use the query from question often, you should use index, as it's likely going to improve query/sorting performance (especially if it fits in your RAM).
BTW, I see that you put an emphasis on the fact that your field is of type date. This doesn't change much, as dates under the hood are stored in Mongo as integers.
Keep in mind though that we don't know how is your collection built (how many documents do you have in collection and how big is single document), so if it gets huge, your specific query might still become very slow in spite of using index, as sort can be quite fast but fetching potentially GBs of data from disk could take lots of time (as you don't use either filtering or projection in your query). In this case, as @ray suggested in his comment, you should use explain() function to examine query execution time and check if index is used and whether it's fetching or sorting stage that takes majority of time.
